# Javascript method to scroll and load

Tags: javascript

I need the Javascript to scroll down, pause for half second -- clear the  hashtag and everything after (in URL bar) and click on page 3 (activation). Can you please explain how I can do this? Basically, I'm trying to have it do multiple things. One after another. Is this possible?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>My Homepage</title>
    <link href="tabs.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />



</head>
<body>

<!-- Here's the button to link --->
<a href="#LinkMe">Link</a> 
<!-- Here's the button to link --->

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<h1>My Homepage</h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<!-- Here's the anchor to link down to --->
<a name="LinkMe"></a>
<!-- Here's the anchor to link down to --->

<!-- Here are the tabs, select tab #2 to open --->
<ol id="toc">
  <li><a href="#page-1"><span>Page 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#page-2"><span>Page 2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#page-3"><span>Page 3</span></a></li>
</ol>
<!-- Here are the tabs, select tab #2 to open --->

<div class="content" id="page-1">
    <h2>Page 1</h2>
    <p>Text...</p>
</div>
<div class="content" id="page-2">
    <h2>Page 2</h2>
    <p>Text...</p>
</div>
<div class="content" id="page-3">
    <h2>Page 3</h2>
    <p>Text...</p>
</div>
<script src="activatables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
activatables('page', ['page-1', 'page-2', 'page-3']);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to append scroll down page function after the following link - how?

```
<a href="#LinkMe&page=page-3">http://fumethis-com.3dcartstores.com/POWER-SERIES-ZERO-STARTER-KIT_p_8.html#ReviewsS</a>
```